# Transporting an Ethernet Port in a LDP Based VPLS Instance on Juniper MX routers

Tags: layer2, juniper-junos, mpls, juniper-mx, vpls

We are currently transporting an Ethernet Port using LDP Based Layer 2 VPN service (P2P PW) in Juniper MX.This P2P LDP PW is up and currently working. Below is the configuration against this:-

```
set interfaces xe-0/0/1 mtu 9192
set interfaces xe-0/0/1 encapsulation ethernet-ccc
set interfaces xe-0/0/1 unit 0 family ccc
set protocols l2circuit neighbor 10.253.0.12 interface xe-0/0/1.0 virtual-circuit-id 70
set protocols l2circuit neighbor 10.253.0.12 interface xe-0/0/1.0 no-control-word
set protocols l2circuit neighbor 10.253.0.12 interface xe-0/0/1.0 mtu 9192
set protocols l2circuit neighbor 10.253.0.12 interface xe-0/0/1.0 ignore-mtu-mismatch
set routing-instances inter-msc-1 interface xe-0/0/1.0
```

We want to transport the same ethernet port but using LDP based VPLS Instance instead of l2circuit.

Is it possible to transport an Ethernet Port using LDP Based Layer 2 VPLS Service in Juniper MX routers? It would be very nice if sample configurations are shared for Juniper MX.

Comment: Wasn't entirely sure if you could run VPLS over a LDP signalled LSP. Quick Google search shows it may be possible -> https://www.juniper.net/documentation/en_US/junos/topics/example/vpls-bgp-ldp-configuring-detailed-solutions.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, LDP VPLS is a pretty standard deployment.  Where it can get confusing is the various types of PE-CE interface encapsulation depending upon the type of service you're running.  In your case of a simple ethernet circuit, it's easy.

Here's a simple example.

**Topology**

```
CE1 [ge-0/0/0] <=> [ge-0/0/1] PE1 [ge-0/0/0] <= LDP => [ge-0/0/0] PE2 [ge-0/0/1] <=> [ge-0/0/0] CE2
```

For example's sake, CE1 and CE2 have a IP's in the same subnet and have no idea they're connected to a VPLS.

**CE1**

```
set interfaces ge-0/0/0 unit 0 family inet address 192.168.1.10/24
```

**CE2**

```
set interfaces ge-0/0/0 unit 0 family inet address 192.168.1.20/24
```

For the PE's, I'm going to skip the LDP configuration and only include what's required for VPLS.

**PE1**

```
set interfaces ge-0/0/1 description to-CE1
set interfaces ge-0/0/1 encapsulation ethernet-vpls
set interfaces ge-0/0/1 unit 0 family vpls

set interfaces lo0 unit 0 family inet address 1.1.1.1/32
set interfaces lo0 unit 0 family mpls
    
set routing-instances VPLS instance-type vpls
set routing-instances VPLS interface ge-0/0/1.0
set routing-instances VPLS protocols vpls no-control-word
set routing-instances VPLS protocols vpls no-tunnel-services
set routing-instances VPLS protocols vpls vpls-id 70
set routing-instances VPLS protocols vpls mtu 9192
set routing-instances VPLS protocols vpls ignore-mtu-mismatch
set routing-instances VPLS protocols vpls neighbor 2.2.2.2   # The loopback of the remote LDP neighbor (PE2)
```

**PE2**

```
set interfaces ge-0/0/1 description to-CE2
set interfaces ge-0/0/1 encapsulation ethernet-vpls
set interfaces ge-0/0/1 unit 0 family vpls

set interfaces lo0 unit 0 family inet address 2.2.2.2/32
set interfaces lo0 unit 0 family mpls

set routing-instances VPLS instance-type vpls
set routing-instances VPLS interface ge-0/0/1.0
set routing-instances VPLS protocols vpls no-control-word
set routing-instances VPLS protocols vpls no-tunnel-services
set routing-instances VPLS protocols vpls vpls-id 70
set routing-instances VPLS protocols vpls mtu 9192
set routing-instances VPLS protocols vpls ignore-mtu-mismatch
set routing-instances VPLS protocols vpls neighbor 1.1.1.1  # The loopback of the remote LDP neighbor (PE1)
```

**Verification**

Let's just look at PE1 VPLS status:

```
jhead@PE> show vpls connections
Layer-2 VPN connections:

Legend for connection status (St)
EI -- encapsulation invalid      NC -- interface encapsulation not CCC/TCC/VPLS
EM -- encapsulation mismatch     WE -- interface and instance encaps not same
VC-Dn -- Virtual circuit down    NP -- interface hardware not present
CM -- control-word mismatch      -> -- only outbound connection is up
CN -- circuit not provisioned    <- -- only inbound connection is up
OR -- out of range               Up -- operational
OL -- no outgoing label          Dn -- down
LD -- local site signaled down   CF -- call admission control failure
RD -- remote site signaled down  SC -- local and remote site ID collision
LN -- local site not designated  LM -- local site ID not minimum designated
RN -- remote site not designated RM -- remote site ID not minimum designated
XX -- unknown connection status  IL -- no incoming label
MM -- MTU mismatch               MI -- Mesh-Group ID not available
BK -- Backup connection          ST -- Standby connection
PF -- Profile parse failure      PB -- Profile busy
RS -- remote site standby    SN -- Static Neighbor
LB -- Local site not best-site   RB -- Remote site not best-site
VM -- VLAN ID mismatch

Legend for interface status
Up -- operational
Dn -- down

Instance: VPLS
  LDP-VPLS State
  VPLS-id: 70
  Mesh-group connections: __ves__
    Neighbor                  Type  St     Time last up          # Up trans
    2.2.2.2(vpls-id 70)       rmt   Up     Dec  3 21:07:21 2020           1
      Remote PE: 2.2.2.2, Negotiated control-word: No
      Incoming label: 262146, Outgoing label: 262146
      Negotiated PW status TLV: No
      Local interface: lsi.1048577, Status: Up, Encapsulation: ETHERNET
        Description: Intf - vpls VPLS neighbor 2.2.2.2 vpls-id 70
      Flow Label Transmit: No, Flow Label Receive: No
```

Finally, we can see that the two CEs can communicate.

```
jhead@CE1> ping 192.168.1.20
PING 192.168.1.20 (192.168.1.20): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 192.168.1.20: icmp_seq=0 ttl=64 time=8.838 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.20: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=4.620 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.20: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=5.639 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.20: icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=3.969 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.20: icmp_seq=4 ttl=64 time=5.594 ms
```

Comment: Thank you very much for providing the detailed configuration. One Confusion. Why there is mentioning of route-distinguisher and route-target in the LDP based VPLS configuration you shared for PEs.At the same time you are also mentioning the remote VPLS LDP peer. In my openion , RD and RT are not required if this is a LDP based VPLS.

Comment: RD and RT are required for BGP signalled VPLS where we need auto discovery and assignment of MPLS Lables at the same time. This is a LDP signalled VPLS.

Comment: Correct, I have fixed my answer to exclude them. Honestly I added it out of sheer habit since I'm typically doing BGP signalled, it works as expected without them.

Comment: Appreciate that.

Comment: @JordanHead, I'm debugging some juniper l2circuit ccc issues and noticed that you have "family mpls" on your loopback interfaces.  Since there is no data-plane neighbor on the loopback, is there a need for `family mpls` on the loopback?  I am fairly newb to juniper's ways of doing things, so I could be totally mistaken here...

Comment: You're correct @MikePennington, you do not need `family mpls` on the loopback, the config fell in as part of an apply-group.